# Bring the call screen to front programmatically from separate app in Android

Tags: android, android-dialer

I am developing a dialer application in Android which needs to set as default replacing the system app.

I can manage incoming and outgoing calls. But in the case of incoming calls, the call screen does not appear in front.

I want to bring the call screen to the front of the dialer app programmatically when an incoming call appears from a separate app. Is there any suitable way to do that?

Sample call screen:
[image: Sample call screen]

Comment: use android Screen Overlay

Comment: Thanks. Is there any intent action that will launch the call screen?